# How to ad "data-" attributes in Scalatags

Tags: scala.js, scalatags

I want to define an input with extended attributes using the "data-" notation. So for example to define:

```
<input type="radio" id="3" data-extra="three"/>
```

Is there a way to do this in Scalatags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"data-extra".attr` to create custom attributes. For example

```
input(tpe := "radio", id := "3", "data-extra".attr := "three")
```

Comment: What should we write here for custom attributes
`<.a( ^.href := "", ^.className := "dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle".attr := "dropdown")`
for "data-toggle"

Comment: Above does not work for me (using version 0.6.29). Had to do attr("data-extra") := "three"

Answer (score 4):

The most convinient way is to use `data(...)`:

```
input(tpe := "radio", id := 3, data("extra") := "three")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now even

`input(tpe := "radio", id := 3, data.extra := "three")`